# Determining a joint distribution of 3 random variables using transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, change-of-variable

My question is if we could define, for example, a diffeomorphism $g: A \rightarrow B$ in the following manner: $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}$ are independent random variables where $X_{1},X_{2} \sim N(0,1)$ and $X_{3} \sim \exp(\lambda)$. Can we now define $U=X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}$ and $\frac{X_{2}+X_{3}}{\sqrt{X_{1}^{2}}}$ consider a transformation defined as $g(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) = (u,v)$ where $(u,v) = \Big( x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3},\frac{x_{2}+x_{3}}{\sqrt{x_{1}^{2}}} \Big)$? If not, is there another way to determine the joint distribution $f_{U,V}(u,v)$? How would one go about this? Can we use a diffeomorphism and a Jacobian matrix?

Comment: You're map is not bijective, since it's range is a two-dimensional set

Comment: You can pretty much define whatever you want. Are you sure about $\sqrt{x_1}$? It could be not defined, since $x_1$ can be negative.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to write $\sqrt{x_{1}^{2}}$ instead. My bad!

Comment: You can reduce this to 2 independent random variables rather than 3 if you consider $X_1$ and $X_{23}=X_2+X_3$.  $X_{23}$ has a pdf of $\frac{1}{2} \lambda  e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda  (\lambda -2 x_{23})} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_{23}-\lambda }{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right)$.